# Finding the smallest positive argument given a summation

Tags: complex-numbers

Take $$\sum_{k=0}^9 z^k = 0$$
I need to find the smallest positive argument possible for the complex number z.
Here's what I figured out so far:
So since this is a GP statement, 
I will have the following where $$z =re^{i\theta}$$:

$$re^{9i\theta} + re^{8i\theta} + re^{7i\theta} + re^{6i\theta} + re^{5i\theta} + re^{4i\theta} + re^{3i\theta} + re^{2i\theta} + re^{i\theta} + 1 = 0$$
Does that mean
$$cos9\theta + cos8\theta + cos7\theta + cos6\theta + cos5\theta + cos4\theta + cos3\theta + cos2\theta + cos\theta + 1 = 0$$

PS: The 1 came from when k=0, and hence equals to 1 and belong to the real portion which is the cos

and
$$sin9\theta + sin8\theta + sin7\theta + sin6\theta + sin5\theta + sin4\theta + sin3\theta + sin2\theta + sin\theta = 0$$?
Is this correct? Am I heading towards a correct approach/direction to this question?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If $z = re^{i\theta}$, then $z^9 = (re^{i\theta})^9 = r^9e^{9i\theta}$. However, you have it as $re^{9i\theta}$ instead. Similarly, you need to correct your expression also for $k = 8$ down to $k = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is
$$\frac{z^{10}-1}{z-1}=0.$$
Its roots are the tenth roots of unity, apart from $1$, namely $\exp(2n\pi i/10)$
for $n\in\{1,2,\ldots,9\}$.

Comment: So from what I understood from your statment, the smallest positive argument will be $$\frac {1}{10} \pi$$?

Comment: See corrected version

Comment: Oh yes, the 2 must be included, since it's $$2k\pi$$
So the answer will be $$\frac {1}{5} \pi$$, right? at n=6 where it has the smallest positive argument.